# Add disabled to select field with reactjs proptype

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to disable a select field by adding `disabled` to the select field as per the bootstrap documentation suggests. I'm using reactjs, so I want to use `props`. For some reason it errors when I create an if/else statement with the prop.

```
<select
 {props.disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}
  className="form-select form-control"
>

disabled: PropTypes.string
```

Comment: you probably need to change the assignment to `disabled={!!props.disabled}`

Comment: thank you, that worked. If you put it in as the solution I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reactjs can't accept strings like that. You need to have some kind of property first.

So changing `{props.disabled ? 'disabled' : ''}` to `disabled={!!props.disabled}` should work.

The `!!` is there to make it a boolean, true/false.

`disabled` accepts true or false (can be string). In other cases, you can use your ternary operator to return a string.